# SQL query takes more than 20 mins

Tags: sql, optimization, toad

I have this software working but now its taking more than 20 mins when i call a report. I have retrieve all querys by separated and this one is taking more than 10 mins generating. I have tried Toad Optimizer but i get nothing.

I have also tried to change the subquery of the end of the WHERE clause but it takes even more with the argument.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
pla_his_consolidado.vendor,   
per_his_maestrovendor.sorteoporapellido,  
per_his_generalempleado.codigovendoranterior, 
per_his_generalempleado.ultimafechaingreso,
CASE per_his_generalempleado.codigoafp WHEN '00' THEN 'ONP' ELSE afp.nombreafp END as nombreafp,    
per_his_generalempleado.numeroafp,
titulopuesto.titulopuesto,   
per_his_maestrovendor.codigoidentificacion,
categoriaempleado.descripcion,   
per_his_vendorempleado.centrocostos,   
maestracentrocostos.descripcion,   
maestralocacion.descripcion,   
per_his_salariobasico.salariobasico,
sys_tabladetablas.descripcion    
from
per_his_vendorempleado 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN maestracentrocostos ON per_his_vendorempleado.centrocostos = maestracentrocostos.centrocostos
    LEFT OUTER JOIN compania ON per_his_vendorempleado.compania = compania.compania
    LEFT OUTER JOIN maestralocacion ON per_his_vendorempleado.locacion = maestralocacion.locacion, 
    per_his_generalempleado 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN afp ON per_his_generalempleado.codigoafp = afp.codigoafp 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys_tabladetablas ON per_his_generalempleado.regimenpensionario = sys_tabladetablas.codigo
    LEFT OUTER JOIN lugartrabajo ON per_his_generalempleado.lugartrabajo = lugartrabajo.lugartrabajo
    LEFT OUTER JOIN titulopuesto ON per_his_generalempleado.codigopuesto = titulopuesto.codigopuesto
    LEFT OUTER JOIN categoriaempleado ON per_his_generalempleado.categoriaempleado = categoriaempleado.categoriaempleado,
pla_his_consolidado,   
per_his_accion,   
per_his_maestrovendor,   
per_his_salariobasico
WHERE 
( pla_his_consolidado.historiaid = per_his_accion.historiaid ) and  
( per_his_accion.idmaestrovendor = per_his_maestrovendor.idmaestrovendor ) and  
( per_his_accion.idgeneralempleado = per_his_generalempleado.idgeneralempleado ) and  
( per_his_accion.idvendorempleado = per_his_vendorempleado.idvendorempleado ) and  
( per_his_accion.idsalariobasico = per_his_salariobasico.idsalariobasico ) and 
        maestralocacion.lugartrabajo = lugartrabajo.lugartrabajo and
per_his_generalempleado.tipoempleado = categoriaempleado.tipoempleado and
        maestralocacion.compania = compania.compania and
        maestracentrocostos.compania = compania.compania and
( ( pla_his_consolidado.codigoperiodo = '201310M1' ) AND  
( pla_his_consolidado.codigoproceso = 'PLLALAMO' ) AND  
( pla_his_consolidado.compania = '000001' ) ) AND  
(sys_tabladetablas.codigotabla = (select min(codigotabla) from sys_tabladetablasatributos where nombrecampo = 'generalempleado.regimenpensionario')) 
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT
gratificacionreintegro.vendor,   
per_his_maestrovendor.sorteoporapellido,  
per_his_generalempleado.codigovendoranterior,  
per_his_generalempleado.ultimafechaingreso, 
CASE per_his_generalempleado.codigoafp WHEN '00' THEN 'ONP' ELSE afp.nombreafp END as nombreafp,    
per_his_generalempleado.numeroafp,
titulopuesto.titulopuesto,   
per_his_maestrovendor.codigoidentificacion,   
categoriaempleado.descripcion,   
per_his_vendorempleado.centrocostos,   
maestracentrocostos.descripcion,   
maestralocacion.descripcion,   
per_his_salariobasico.salariobasico,
sys_tabladetablas.descripcion
from
per_his_vendorempleado 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN maestracentrocostos ON per_his_vendorempleado.centrocostos = maestracentrocostos.centrocostos
    LEFT OUTER JOIN compania ON per_his_vendorempleado.compania = compania.compania
    LEFT OUTER JOIN maestralocacion ON per_his_vendorempleado.locacion = maestralocacion.locacion, 
    per_his_generalempleado 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN afp ON per_his_generalempleado.codigoafp = afp.codigoafp 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys_tabladetablas ON per_his_generalempleado.regimenpensionario = sys_tabladetablas.codigo
    LEFT OUTER JOIN lugartrabajo ON per_his_generalempleado.lugartrabajo = lugartrabajo.lugartrabajo
    LEFT OUTER JOIN titulopuesto ON per_his_generalempleado.codigopuesto = titulopuesto.codigopuesto
    LEFT OUTER JOIN categoriaempleado ON per_his_generalempleado.categoriaempleado = categoriaempleado.categoriaempleado,
gratificacionreintegro,   
per_his_accion,   
per_his_maestrovendor,   
per_his_salariobasico
WHERE 
( gratificacionreintegro.historiaid = per_his_accion.historiaid ) and  
( per_his_accion.idmaestrovendor = per_his_maestrovendor.idmaestrovendor ) and  
( per_his_accion.idgeneralempleado = per_his_generalempleado.idgeneralempleado ) and  
( per_his_accion.idvendorempleado = per_his_vendorempleado.idvendorempleado ) and  
( per_his_accion.idsalariobasico = per_his_salariobasico.idsalariobasico ) and 
        maestralocacion.lugartrabajo = lugartrabajo.lugartrabajo and
per_his_generalempleado.tipoempleado = categoriaempleado.tipoempleado and
        maestralocacion.compania = compania.compania and
        maestracentrocostos.compania = compania.compania and
( ( gratificacionreintegro.periodoproceso = '201310M1' ) AND  
( gratificacionreintegro.proceso = 'PLLALAMO' ) AND  
( gratificacionreintegro.compania = '000001' ) ) AND  
(sys_tabladetablas.codigotabla = (select min(codigotabla) from sys_tabladetablasatributos where nombrecampo = 'generalempleado.regimenpensionario'))    
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT
salario.vendor,   
per_his_maestrovendor.sorteoporapellido,  
per_his_generalempleado.codigovendoranterior,  
per_his_generalempleado.ultimafechaingreso,   
CASE per_his_generalempleado.codigoafp WHEN '00' THEN 'ONP' ELSE afp.nombreafp END as nombreafp,
per_his_generalempleado.numeroafp,
titulopuesto.titulopuesto,   
per_his_maestrovendor.codigoidentificacion,   
categoriaempleado.descripcion,   
per_his_vendorempleado.centrocostos,   
maestracentrocostos.descripcion,   
maestralocacion.descripcion,   
per_his_salariobasico.salariobasico,
sys_tabladetablas.descripcion
from
per_his_vendorempleado 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN maestracentrocostos ON per_his_vendorempleado.centrocostos = maestracentrocostos.centrocostos
    LEFT OUTER JOIN compania ON per_his_vendorempleado.compania = compania.compania
    LEFT OUTER JOIN maestralocacion ON per_his_vendorempleado.locacion = maestralocacion.locacion, 
    per_his_generalempleado 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN afp ON per_his_generalempleado.codigoafp = afp.codigoafp 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys_tabladetablas ON per_his_generalempleado.regimenpensionario = sys_tabladetablas.codigo
    LEFT OUTER JOIN lugartrabajo ON per_his_generalempleado.lugartrabajo = lugartrabajo.lugartrabajo
    LEFT OUTER JOIN titulopuesto ON per_his_generalempleado.codigopuesto = titulopuesto.codigopuesto
    LEFT OUTER JOIN categoriaempleado ON per_his_generalempleado.categoriaempleado = categoriaempleado.categoriaempleado,
salario,   
per_his_accion,   
per_his_maestrovendor,   
per_his_salariobasico
WHERE 
( salario.historiaid = per_his_accion.historiaid ) and  
( per_his_accion.idmaestrovendor = per_his_maestrovendor.idmaestrovendor ) and  
( per_his_accion.idgeneralempleado = per_his_generalempleado.idgeneralempleado ) and  
( per_his_accion.idvendorempleado = per_his_vendorempleado.idvendorempleado ) and  
( per_his_accion.idsalariobasico = per_his_salariobasico.idsalariobasico ) and
        maestralocacion.lugartrabajo = lugartrabajo.lugartrabajo and
per_his_generalempleado.tipoempleado = categoriaempleado.tipoempleado and
        maestralocacion.compania = compania.compania and
        maestracentrocostos.compania = compania.compania and
( ( salario.periodoproceso = '201310M1' ) AND  
( salario.codigoproceso = 'PLLALAMO' ) AND  
( salario.compania = '000001' ) ) AND  
(sys_tabladetablas.codigotabla = (select min(codigotabla) from sys_tabladetablasatributos where nombrecampo = 'generalempleado.regimenpensionario'))    
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT
(vacacion.vendor),   
per_his_maestrovendor.sorteoporapellido, 
per_his_generalempleado.codigovendoranterior,   
per_his_generalempleado.ultimafechaingreso,   
CASE per_his_generalempleado.codigoafp WHEN '00' THEN 'ONP' ELSE afp.nombreafp END as nombreafp,
per_his_generalempleado.numeroafp,
titulopuesto.titulopuesto,   
per_his_maestrovendor.codigoidentificacion,   
categoriaempleado.descripcion,   
per_his_vendorempleado.centrocostos,   
maestracentrocostos.descripcion,   
maestralocacion.descripcion,   
per_his_salariobasico.salariobasico,
sys_tabladetablas.descripcion
from
per_his_vendorempleado 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN maestracentrocostos ON per_his_vendorempleado.centrocostos = maestracentrocostos.centrocostos
    LEFT OUTER JOIN compania ON per_his_vendorempleado.compania = compania.compania
    LEFT OUTER JOIN maestralocacion ON per_his_vendorempleado.locacion = maestralocacion.locacion, 
    per_his_generalempleado 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN afp ON per_his_generalempleado.codigoafp = afp.codigoafp 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys_tabladetablas ON per_his_generalempleado.regimenpensionario = sys_tabladetablas.codigo
    LEFT OUTER JOIN lugartrabajo ON per_his_generalempleado.lugartrabajo = lugartrabajo.lugartrabajo
    LEFT OUTER JOIN titulopuesto ON per_his_generalempleado.codigopuesto = titulopuesto.codigopuesto
    LEFT OUTER JOIN categoriaempleado ON per_his_generalempleado.categoriaempleado = categoriaempleado.categoriaempleado,
vacacion,   
per_his_accion,   
per_his_maestrovendor,   
per_his_salariobasico
WHERE 
( vacacion.historiaid = per_his_accion.historiaid ) and  
( per_his_accion.idmaestrovendor = per_his_maestrovendor.idmaestrovendor ) and  
( per_his_accion.idgeneralempleado = per_his_generalempleado.idgeneralempleado ) and  
( per_his_accion.idvendorempleado = per_his_vendorempleado.idvendorempleado ) and  
( per_his_accion.idsalariobasico = per_his_salariobasico.idsalariobasico ) and 
        maestralocacion.lugartrabajo = lugartrabajo.lugartrabajo and
per_his_generalempleado.tipoempleado = categoriaempleado.tipoempleado and
        maestralocacion.compania = compania.compania and
        maestracentrocostos.compania = compania.compania and
( ( vacacion.periodoproceso = '201310M1' ) AND  
( vacacion.proceso = 'PLLALAMO' ) AND  
( vacacion.compania = '000001' ) ) AND  
(sys_tabladetablas.codigotabla = (select min(codigotabla) from sys_tabladetablasatributos where nombrecampo = 'generalempleado.regimenpensionario'))    
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT
(reservas.vendor),   
per_his_maestrovendor.sorteoporapellido,
per_his_generalempleado.codigovendoranterior,    
per_his_generalempleado.ultimafechaingreso,   
CASE per_his_generalempleado.codigoafp WHEN '00' THEN 'ONP' ELSE afp.nombreafp END as nombreafp,
per_his_generalempleado.numeroafp,
titulopuesto.titulopuesto,   
per_his_maestrovendor.codigoidentificacion,  
categoriaempleado.descripcion,   
per_his_vendorempleado.centrocostos,   
maestracentrocostos.descripcion,   
maestralocacion.descripcion,   
per_his_salariobasico.salariobasico, 
sys_tabladetablas.descripcion
from
per_his_vendorempleado 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN maestracentrocostos ON per_his_vendorempleado.centrocostos = maestracentrocostos.centrocostos
    LEFT OUTER JOIN compania ON per_his_vendorempleado.compania = compania.compania
    LEFT OUTER JOIN maestralocacion ON per_his_vendorempleado.locacion = maestralocacion.locacion, 
    per_his_generalempleado 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN afp ON per_his_generalempleado.codigoafp = afp.codigoafp 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys_tabladetablas ON per_his_generalempleado.regimenpensionario = sys_tabladetablas.codigo
    LEFT OUTER JOIN lugartrabajo ON per_his_generalempleado.lugartrabajo = lugartrabajo.lugartrabajo
    LEFT OUTER JOIN titulopuesto ON per_his_generalempleado.codigopuesto = titulopuesto.codigopuesto
    LEFT OUTER JOIN categoriaempleado ON per_his_generalempleado.categoriaempleado = categoriaempleado.categoriaempleado,
reservas,   
per_his_accion,   
per_his_maestrovendor,   
per_his_salariobasico
WHERE 
( reservas.historiaid = per_his_accion.historiaid ) and  
( per_his_accion.idmaestrovendor = per_his_maestrovendor.idmaestrovendor ) and  
( per_his_accion.idgeneralempleado = per_his_generalempleado.idgeneralempleado ) and  
( per_his_accion.idvendorempleado = per_his_vendorempleado.idvendorempleado ) and  
( per_his_accion.idsalariobasico = per_his_salariobasico.idsalariobasico ) and 
        maestralocacion.lugartrabajo = lugartrabajo.lugartrabajo and
per_his_generalempleado.tipoempleado = categoriaempleado.tipoempleado and
        maestralocacion.compania = compania.compania and
        maestracentrocostos.compania = compania.compania and
( ( reservas.periodoproceso = '201310M1' ) AND  
( reservas.proceso = 'PLLALAMO' ) AND  
( reservas.compania = '000001' ) ) AND  
(sys_tabladetablas.codigotabla = (select min(codigotabla) from sys_tabladetablasatributos where nombrecampo = 'generalempleado.regimenpensionario'))
```

Comment: Is this in Oracle? Have you checked the execution plan to see where the pain points are?

Comment: Posted SQL with syntax highlighting: http://pastebucket.com/27151

Comment: What's the volume in your tables? Joins can generate very big relations depending on the number of lines.
Are there indexes on the columns on which you do your joins?
What are the relations between your different tables (one-to-one? one-to-many? many-to-many?

Comment: you have a lot of joins which could take up some time, especially if your indexes aren't set up properly. since union all give you all results this could return a lot of data. see this link for info on the difference between union all and union: http://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/query/union-all/index.htm

Comment: Even without knowing the structure, this query has a lot of issues.  All of the subqueries, UNION ALL, SELECT DISTINCT, CASE statements and a whole bunch of joins all add up to a lot of overhead.  I'm surprised it runs as fast as it is.

Comment: Can you confirm the database that you are using??  Is it Oracle?

Comment: Seems that some of the where conditions could be moved to the join conditions. I always figure the sooner the better. Do you _need_ outer joins?

Comment: The order of joins seem wrong. Considering how much we know about `pla_his_consolidado` you'd want to start off with that as soon as possible, so you eliminate joining unnecessary data.

Comment: @towr - smart optimizers reorder joins anyways, so that may not help any.  Some of those `WHERE` conditions are turning them from `LEFT JOIN`s into `INNER JOIN`s, though.

Comment: We need to know a _lot_ more about this query - for instance, you're using some implicit join syntax in there (comma-separated!) - Combined with placing comparisons into the `WHERE` clause, it's making it tough to tell what type of join those are supposed to be.  `SELECT DISTINCT` is doing you no good, because of `UNION ALL`.  From a quick glance, you should be able to reduce this to one section - most of the joins/conditions are the same, no grouping... it just looks different in the first column.  Try cleaning it up some first.